# Dynamic memory allocation of smart pointers declared in a class in C++

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers

I see such kind of code regularly in C++

```
struct StructExample{
    StructExample(int a, int b):mA(a), mB(b){
    }
    int mA;
    int mB;
}

class ExampleClass{
public:
    void foo();
private:
    std::unique_ptr<StructExample> mStructPtr;
};

void ExampleClass::foo(){
    while(condition){
        //....other code....

        mStructPtr  = std::make_unique<StructExample>(100, 200);

        //....other code....
    }
}

int main(){
    ExampleClass obj;
    obj.foo();
}
```

Since the lifetime of `structPtr` is the lifetime of `obj`.

**Question** -
`mStructPtr  = std::make_unique<StructExample>(100, 200);`, does `std::make_unique` keep creating new memory without destroying the old. If so will it not increase the memory indefinitely.

Comment: [The assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D) will release the existing memory, if any. So the assignment to `mStructPtr` will release the old memory of the pointer.

Comment: *Or am I missing something basic here ?* Yes, you are missing reading the [manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/operator%3D).

Comment: @273K, yes...now clear

Comment: Yes you miss something really basic : in this case there is absolutely no reason to even use a smartpointer. Just make `StructExample` a normal member (and if you need implement a move constructor). unique_ptr is only needed when you have polymorphism (which you don't). And probably on embedded you don't want dynamic memory allocation as much anyway

Comment: If you've written code that reallocates memory in every iteration of a loop, you should think about whether there's a way of avoiding this. There is a pretty simple one here: assign new values to the member variables instead of reallocating the memory. Note that changing the type of `mStructPtr` to `std::optional<StructExample>` is worth a consideration, since it avoids allocating memory dynamically completely (you could simply use `mStructPtr.emplace(100, 200);` instead of `mStructPtr  = std::make_unique...;`, if you do this...)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, the question wasn't about using a smart pointer or a normal member, I was missing the point that an assignment operator to an unique pointer which is  already managing an object actually clears previous memory before assigning

Comment: @Nithin707 Maybe my answer was a bit too strong but I still think you should look into move assignment. If you want to replace (or clear) the content of a unique_ptr explicitly use the [reset](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) method.  Otherwise only assign once in your code.

Comment: @fabian In multi process systems, eg a camera service servicing multiple clients, new shared pointers are allocated memory in every loop and given to each client requesting the camera data, so my context is more toward that

Comment: @PepijnKramer, move assignment is a good idea, since I can transfer ownership in this case...I am working on a code base where memory allocation is done every loop and the ownership is given to multiple clients, so assigning once is not the use case

Answer (score 1):

If `mStructPtr` already manages an object and a new `std::unique_ptr` instance is move-assigned to it, then `std::unique_ptr::operator=` will destroy the object previously managed by `mStructPtr`.

If that wasn't the case then assignment to a `std::unique_ptr` would be impossible to use reliably and it wouldn't be provided at all. The whole point of `std::unique_ptr` is that you *shouldn't* have to explicitly take care of the lifetime of the managed object. As long as you have a `std::unique_ptr` referring to the object you know it is alive and as soon as you don't have any such `std::unique_ptr` you know it has been destroyed.